# Deploying custom field on managed package object using the SFDX cli fails

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api

We use a number of managed packages in our org. Two that are relevant here are Salesforce CPQ (namespace SBQQ__) and Chargebee (Namespace chargebeeapps).

We have created a custom field `CB_Quote_Id__c` on the SBQQ__Quote object (CPQ Quote). When created manually in an org, this works fine. However, if we try to deploy source-tracked metadata using the `sfdx` cli, we get a very odd error: `An object 'SBQQ__Quote__c.CB_Quote_ID__c' of type CustomField was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory`. Google/DDG searching shows that others have hit this error and that it centered around a piece of metadata being owned by two package directories. Which makes sense, except for the fact that we only have one package directory specified in our `sfdx-project.json` file. Specifically, we have:

```json
"packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true,
      "package": "myCompanyHere-misc",
      "versionNumber": "1.0.0.NEXT"
    }
  ]
```

(Edit the second) - I have *also* tried changing the field name. No custom field is deployable to the sbcc__quote__c object.

I've also run `export SFDX_MDAPI_TEMP_DIR=.tmp` to set the MDAPI temp dir to something can inspect *after* the command runs. What I'm finding is that the package.xml file that's generated does indeed list my custom field:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>SBQQ__Quote__c.AccountName_Template__c</members>
        <members>SBQQ__Quote__c.Approval_Needed__c</members>
        <members>SBQQ__Quote__c.Approval_Status__c</members>
        <members>SBQQ__Quote__c.CB_Quote_ID__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
...
```

and when I look in the object folder, I find the expected metadata file for the object: `SBQQ__Quote__c.object` and it contains the following XML:

```xml
    <fields>
        <fullName>CB_Quote_Id__c</fullName>
        <caseSensitive>false</caseSensitive>
        <externalId>true</externalId>
        <label>CB Quote Id</label>
        <length>50</length>
        <required>false</required>
        <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
        <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
        <type>Text</type>
        <unique>true</unique>
    </fields>
```

To my eye, this looks like correct xml for the field, and I'm finding this in the metadata package directory the CLI is creating. It looks all the world like it should be working fine. I'm not sure if this is a CLI issue, a metadata API issue or ?? The deployment status page in my scratch org shows this error: `An object 'SBQQ__Quote__c.CBQuoteID__c' of type CustomField was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory`

Ok relevant facts time:

- `sfdx` version: sfdx-cli/7.200.7 darwin-arm64 node-v16.19.0
- Scratch org pod: CS252
- Deploying v56.0 metadata with REST API v57.0 connection

edit the first:
@phil_w has asked for the following information:

- Using source-tracking formatted code.
- Using `sfdx project deploy -c` as the command line.
- Using the above command line, SFDX is generating a package.xml, and a folder and deploying via the metadata api (as I believe it always does)
- Here's a screen shot of the folder structure. You're looking at a folder stored under force_app/main/default/objects

Update: Tried a "source-tracking" based command here's the output:
[image: force source push output.]

[image]

Comment: Are you using source or mdapi format? The folder and XML structure for objects is quite different between the two (mdapi has the fields and other metadata in the object's XML, whereas source has separate XML files for the fields in a suborder of the object folder). With the latter you also need a minimal object XML file. It seems likely to me you do not have the correct files and folders. You should [edit] the question to show the CLI command you use, and show the folder structure, file names and full content of the file(s) involved.

Comment: I very much support not having static namespace references in your package source, but - does the behavior change if you name the files using your package's namespace?

Comment: @DavidReed - could you expand on this a bit more please? i'm not sure I understand how to test? We don't have a package namespace for our code.

Comment: Probably not the issue but ID vs Id worries me.

Comment: @KevinJones - good callout, and at this point, I'm willing to test anything. Having just tested this, I can confirm that this isn't the issue.